# Spring boot hot deploy jar and undeploy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm sorry this is not a typical stackoverflow question, I'm not looking to fix some of my code, but I'm trying to find a solution for my application.

Context:
I'm building an spring boot application that can expose/consume custom APIs (these can be REST or otherwise).
The API connectors can be built and compiled outside the application, following a template.

The problem:
I need a way to programatically load code compiled outside the application and run it inside my application with 0 downtime, I also need to be able to undeploy the jar no longer used.

Comment: Zero downtime is non trivial to do. You will probably need to look into cloud technologies to replace deployments instead of hot deploy.

Comment: For less strict downtime requirements consider a normal web server where you deploy war files.

Comment: I changed my approach a little. The application is deployed on kubernetes, so instead of deploying the new api connector as part of the api module, I will create internal APIs that give access to the data to be used by the connectors and I will deploy them as separate module.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [OSGi](https://www.osgi.org/) to achieve [something](https://github.com/Neone-character-creator/neone-character-creator-core) like this, though it only involved making frontend apps packaged in jars available, rather than backend APIs.

First, I created an application with an embedded OSGi runtime (Apache Felix, specifically). These runtimes normally watch a local directory to find jar files they can load automatically; I used custom code to watch an AWS S3 bucket and loaded them explicitly when new files were uploaded to the bucket.

I setup listeners in my application for when the runtime loaded or unloaded plugin [services](https://www.knopflerfish.org/osgi_service_tutorial.html) that implemented my special marker interface and registered/unregistered them when these events happened.

When requests would come in, I would determine which plugin the requests were meant for via the request path and load needed files from the plugin archive.